# two layers of quotes around a bash variable

Tags: r, bash

I've written a bash script that makes a series of R scripts. However, Ive run into difficulty quoting a bash variable to echo to the R script as a file to be read into R. I have

```
echo "loadings_file <- $loadings ; calls_file <- $file" | cat - template.R > temp && mv temp $scriptname
```

$loadings and $file are files I want R to read in. But when I run it as is they end up in the R script with no quotes aroudn them for R to treat as a string. How do I make sure they're quoted in R but still expanded in bash first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo "loadings_file <- '$loadings' ; calls_file <- '$file'"
```

If you specifically need double quoting:

```
echo "loadings_file <- \"$loadings\" ; calls_file <- \"$file\""
```

Comment: `'` prevents the evaluation of `$file`.

Comment: @sgibb No not when within `""`.

Comment: That's why I thought you couldn't double quote. But it does work. Thanks! Nothing quite as rewarding as getting things like to work.

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape your quotes (`\"`) around the variables:

```
echo "loadings_file <- \"$loadings\" ; calls_file <- \"$file\"" | cat - template.R > temp && mv temp $scriptname
```